Non-orientability in electromagnetism
I'm currently studying E&M and I have a question related to the mathematical formalism of the theory. Electrodynamics depends heavily on the divergence and Stokes's theorem which in their mathematical statements require an orientable manifold, so what will be the case if we consider electrodynamics over non-orientable surfaces? (I.e., if there is a time-varying electric or magnetic field on the Möbius strip, will there be an induced effect on the boundary?)

Maybe this will interest you over on math overflow, Flux through a Môbius strip

You can always use the differential  form of Maxwell's equations in 3D space, then draw any surface you like (orientable or not) and see what are the values of the fields there. May be I am missing some subtlety in your question. Or are you asking to define EM in a 2D world with a mobius strip topology?

Hey Pato, I didn't mean constructing EM in 2-dimensions, I gave the analogy of Möbius strip as it is the primary example for non-orientable surfaces, what I meant is that how we are going to make use of the geenralized Stocks's Theorem and its special cases and we don't have an orientable manifold which is one of the requirements of the theorem, otherwise the interal will not be defined or covariant if you wish, the orientation structure is necessary in order to define integral on manifolds. Now speaking physically, can we conduct an experiment and see whether EM effects will happen over NonOS

You can only use Stokes's theorem is the assumptions are valid, I am not a mathematician, but if it doesn't work on non orientable surfaces, then you just cannot use it in that case to make your calculations. But nothing weird will happen in our physical world, because it is orientable, the non orientable surface is only in your imagination, and is not even useful to make calculations.

The boundary of the Möbius strip is (topologically) a circle $C$. You can find an orientable surface $S$ with $\partial S= C$, and the flux of the magnetic field doesn't depend on the choice if $S$. So you don't have to care about the flux on the Möbius strip (which isn't defined) when you want to calculate the induced voltage due to the temporal change of the magnetic field. Simply chose instead of the Möbius strip $M$ an orientable surface $S$ which has the same boundary as that of $M$ and calculate the flux on that surface.

It is, of course, not possible to do experiments to test out how E&M might behave in a non-orientable 3-dimensional space, since (as far as we can tell) our own 3-space is orientable and topologically trivial.  So we're in the realm of thought experiments here.
Even in a non-orientable 3-space, there would be no impediment to using the divergence theorem and Stokes's theorem locally.  Any manifold is locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$;  and so you could still (for example) apply Gauss's law to relate the the amount of charge inside some (small) finite sphere to the electric flux through that sphere.
Where the non-orientability of the space would come into play is in which vector fields and charge configurations would be admissible in such a space.  This would not strictly speaking be due to the orientability of the space per se, but due to its global topological properties.  As an example of this, suppose our spatial manifold $\mathcal{M}$ was a 3-torus, containing a single point charge $Q \neq 0$.  On the one hand, the integral of $\rho$ over $\mathcal{M}$ would be $Q/\epsilon_0$.  If Gauss's Law held, then the flux integral of $\vec{E}$ over the manifold's boundary $\partial \mathcal{M}$ should also be equal to this.  But $\partial \mathcal{M}$ is the empty set, since $\mathcal{M}$ has no boundary.  So the flux integral is zero, and we have a contradiction.  We conclude that either the net charge in this space must be zero, or that Gauss's Law fails somewhere in this space.
The 3-torus is orientable, of course;  but I would expect that you could make similar arguments concerning the amount of charge and/or current present globally in a non-orientable 3-manifold (some kind of Klein-bottle-like toroidal space, for example).  Such arguments might involve dividing the space into two portions, each of which is orientable independently; applying Gauss's Law to each one; and then relating the flux  on the boundaries of each half to the amounts of charge present.
